# Error Transaction revert / no balance but Balance is there

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

```
contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor ()
        ERC20("StableToken", "STBL")
        public
    {
        // Mint 100 tokens to msg.sender
        // Similar to how
        // 1 dollar = 100 cents
        // 1 token = 1 * (10 ** decimals)
        //Unter welcher eth adresse der contract deployed wird = msg.sender
        _mint(0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4, 1000000);
        _mint(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2,1000000);
        
    }
}

contract testProtocol {
//Gibt Guthaben an STBL Tokens zurück der aufrufenden Adresse
function checkStableTokenBalance() public returns(uint256) {
    STBLInterface stbl = STBLInterface(stblContract);
    return stbl.balanceOf(msg.sender);  
}

//transfer
function transferStableToken(address _recipient, uint256 _amount) public payable returns(bool) {
    STBLInterface stbl = STBLInterface(stblContract);
    return stbl.transfer(_recipient, _amount);
}

function approveStableToken(address _spender, uint256 _amount) public returns (bool){
    STBLInterface stbl = STBLInterface(stblContract);
    return stbl.approve(_spender, _amount);
    
}

//transferFrom
function transferFromStableToken(address _sender, address _recipient, uint256 _amount) public payable returns(bool) {
    STBLInterface stbl = STBLInterface(stblContract);
    return stbl.transferFrom(_sender, _recipient, _amount);
}

}
```

I have this setup in remix , i mint erc20 tokens and i can check the balance also from the contract testProtocol and its showing the right balance. So the function "checkStableTokenBalance()" is working.
But when i want to transfer the tokens with function "transferStableToken", i get the Error that transaction is reverted "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance".
Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Function `checkStableTokenBalance` returns the balance of the caller (`msg.sender`).

Function `transferStableToken` attempts to transfer from the contract (`this`).

Those are obviously two different accounts (Ethereum addresses).

Comment: ok but how can i modify the code to make it work the way its intended?

Comment: @blossom: I cannot answer this question in a comment here. And I cannot answer it as part of my answer, because your original question is about "`no balance but Balance is there`". So please post your new question in a new post, and if you feel that I have answered your current question here, then please accept my answer by clicking on the V next to it.